# So i have been trying to solve this issue. I have developed a react app and wrote some back end to it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling

When i try to run the backend it is successfully connected and when i tried to run the front end part it says it is missing a module.I am running both front end and backend in separate terminals.Even though i did the error still occurs. This is my file structure.

```
recipe/
  ├── recipe-book-app/
  │     ├── src/
  │     │    ├── index.js
  │     │    └── ...
  │     └── ...
  │
  └── recipe-book-backend/
        ├── index.js
        ├── middleware/
        ├── models/
        ├── routes/
        └── ...
```

and i am running the npm start in the following directory

```
PS C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\recipe\recipe-book-app> npm start

npm start

> recipe-book-app@0.1.0 start
> node recipe-book-backend/index.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\sasha\Desktop\recipe\recipe-book-app\recipe-book-backend\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v20.3.1

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the error, `npm start` launches the `node recipe-book-backend/index.js` command, from what I can determine I would say that your problem comes from your *package.json*, either you don't have package.json in your *recipe-book-app* folder and your `npm start` will therefore type the *package.json* in the recipe folder, or you have copy-pasted the *package.json* from your backend and in this case you must modify the commands executed by npm start